# How can I stack several 3D elevation layers?

Tags: qgis, mapbox, arcscene, qgis2threejs, gvsig

So far I have been using qgis2threejs to display different layers at once like one terrain elevation layer and one population data layer. The result through is that the 3D population data is not sitting on "the mountains" but on flat   floor with z=0, sometimes hidden below the terrain surface. The layers are displayed in parallel but not on top of each other which should be case.
I could add both layers and display them as one but then I can't manipulation the colors individually with is essential for my work.
I am using qgis2threejs because it is intended for online users to explore. But I am also willing to learn other tools. I am just unsure which can do what I am looking for.
Maybe Mapbox? Deck GL? gVSIG? Do need the commercial ArcScene?
It would really be good if it's possible to explore the resulting 3D visualization on a website.

Below you see a screenshot of my issue. The peaks of population data appear under the mountainous surface, instead of on top of it. I projected the colors on the elevation layer so but thats missing the 3D effect of course.
[image]

Comment: I assume that your elevation layer is a raster (is it?), but what about your population layer - is it a raster or vector?

Comment: yes, it's both raster.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you need to convert a 2D vector layer to 3D based on a DEM or you only need to show the vector data on the DEM.

For the first case you can see this post: https://blog.gvsig.org/2019/02/06/towards-gvsig-2-5-plugin-to-convert-a-2d-vector-layer-to-3d-from-a-dem/

If you want to show vector data on a 3D view you can watch these videos:
https://blog.gvsig.org/2018/02/26/gis-applied-to-municipality-management-module-15-gvsig-3d/
https://youtu.be/aoy-JwkFPeo?t=1947
(at the second one I've linked it to the moment where 3D View is shown.

Finally, if you need to learn how to start working on gvSIG (symbology, labelling, editing tools, geoprocessing...) here you have a video about it: https://blog.gvsig.org/2018/03/21/learning-scripting-on-gvsig-in-half-an-hour-videotutorial-available/

Comment: Thank you for the response, Mario. I have raster layers in geoTIFF format, no vector layers. In QGIS I can use the plugin qgis2threejs to visualize them in 3D, using pixel values as Z-coordinates. I am not sure if your suggestions help me solve my problem though. Imagine artificial peaks or pillars on top of a mountainous terrain. Each of them has a different height and corresponding color. The ground level is always defined by the terrain elevation of their coordinates from the other geoTIFF. QGIS with qgis2threejs seems to only allow a single ground-level for all coordinates and layers.

Comment: Yes, you can select pixel value as elevation at raster layer properties, at "3D" tab. It's shown at the video that I told you, at this moment: https://youtu.be/aoy-JwkFPeo?t=2318 About the last video, I put the link to scripting training. The video about how to start using gvSIG is this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OcyhevNxTC8